# android open homepage over the network

Tags: android, networking, android-intent, adb

I know it is easy ,if I can use adb .

```
$ export ADBHOST=192.168.11.14(device's IP)
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
```

in this status.I can use adb with wireless.so next,

```
$ adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW http://www.google.com
```

in this status. I can see google page in my android device .

I want to do it without adb. I want to develop a app which send a intent to one device via tcp without install any app. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Android doesn't wirelessly accept Intents from other devices, except via adb.  It would be 100% insecure to do so-  anyone could send any intent to anyone.  It would be spam central.  You need an app on both devices.

Comment: OK,thank you ,do you know some other way to control another android without install anything?(bluetooth.NFC,BLE,......)

Comment: No.  That's called a security hole.  They don't do it on purpose.